# Why is my nextjs router not return query params?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/123?foo=bar of my nextjs app
I get the following when I print out `router.query`

```
{id: "123"}
```

What could be the reasons it is not adding `foo: 'bar'` to the query object?

Comment: It is usually due to your route path define, could you also put it here?

Answer (score -1):

Your [file layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) should look like this:

```
pages/
  users/
   [id].js
```

Having just tested this, the returned query object is `{"foo":"bar","id":"123"}`.

Answer (score -1):

I had to add a next.config.js file with the following

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/pages/:slug*',
        destination: '/:slug*'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```